# JAXB - Overriding datatype of an element

Tags: jaxb

I am using JAXB with the following customized binding :

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.0" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="2000">
        <jaxb:serializable />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
        <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="test.xsd" node="/xs:schema//xs:complexType[@name='EN']//xs:element[@name='family']">
            <jaxb:property>
                <jaxb:baseType name="java.lang.String" />
            </jaxb:property>
        </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

to handle this schema (test.xsd):

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:complexType name="EN" mixed="true">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="ANY">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xsd:element name="family" type="en.family"/>
               </xsd:choice>
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="en.family" mixed="true">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:restriction base="ENXP">
         </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ENXP" mixed="true">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="ST">
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ST" mixed="true">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:restriction base="ED">
         </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ED" mixed="true">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="BIN">
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="BIN" abstract="true" mixed="true">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="ANY">
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ANY" abstract="true">
      <xsd:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
      </xsd:attribute>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

And I experiencing this problem :

```
[ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this property customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
  line 6 of file://home/user/test/jaxbelem_binding.xml

[ERROR] (the above customization is attached to the following location in the schema)
  line 7 of file://home/user/test/test.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

What's wrong with my binding file?
It's yaling about `jaxb:property`, but when the latter is deleted, no overriding happens!

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks in advance folks!

Comment: I tryied this too :  

    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='en.family']">
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.lan.String" parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseString" printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printString" />
    </jaxb:bindings>

But I am getting the same error "compiler was unable to honor this javaType customization"

Answer (score 3):

I have had luck nesting the `jxb:bindings node` tag inside of the `jxb:bindings schemaLocation` tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" ?>
<jxb:bindings version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="test.xsd"> 
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='family']">
            <jxb:property >
                <jxb:baseType name="java.lang.String"></jxb:baseType>
            </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

also:

- while your note xpath to 'family' works, it seems overly complicated. I updated it to one that works given your example xsd (as long as there is only one element with name='family' it will work)